# Undefined when displaying subscribe data for nested classes

Tags: html, angular, nested

I am working with Angular 8.

With a nested class, I am trying to display data obtained from a subscribe operation to an observable. It works for the main attributes of the class (id, name), but I am getting an 'undefined' error whenever I try to access the child class (Players), at least until the data is finally feed by the observable.

The data structure is simple. I have a tournament with players in it.

```
import { Player } from './player';

export class Tournament {
   id: string;
   name: string;

   public Players: Player[];   
}
```

The service is as follows. It returns the data correctly, in the format expected by the `Tournament` class.

```
  getTournament(id): Observable<Tournament> {
    return this.http.get<Tournament>(this.apiURL + '/tournaments/' + id)    
    .pipe(
      retry(1),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    )
  }
```

The component, below. It initializes the data correctly as long as I don't try to access the child component, which of course is undefined since I declared the variable `tournament` as of type `any`

```
export class TournamentEditComponent implements OnInit {

  id = this.actRoute.snapshot.params['id'];
  tournament: any = [];

  constructor(public restApi: RestApiService, public actRoute: ActivatedRoute, public router: Router){}

  ngOnInit() { 
    this.getTournament();
  }

  // Get tournament data to feed screen
  getTournament() {
    this.restApi.getTournament(this.id).subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.tournament = data;
      console.log('Tournament:\n',this.tournament);
    })
  }
```

```html
  <h4 class="mb-2">Players ({{tournament.Players.length}})</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="">
        <div *ngFor="let player of tournament.Players">
          <ngb-panel title="{{player.username}}">
            <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
              <p>{{player.name}} {{player.surname}}</p>
            </ng-template>
          </ngb-panel>
        </div>
      </ngb-accordion>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The console seen in the component shows the following data (I've deleted some unnecessary data from it):

```
{
  id: 1
  name: "Express1"
  prize: 1000
  rounds: 25
  createdAt: "2020-01-09T17:03:13.772Z"
  updatedAt: "2020-01-13T09:48:28.582Z"
  Players: Array(2)
    0: {id: 1, username: "aaaa", name: "a", surname: "b", email: "ab@mail.com"}
    1: {id: 3, username: "bbbb", name: "b", surname: "a", email: "ba@mail.com"}    
    length: 2
  __proto__: Array(0)
  __proto__: Object
}
```

Whenever I try to access the object/class Player from the HTML page, I get an undefined error, even if at the end it shows the data correctly. I have tried changing the variable tournament of the component to a variable of type `Tournament` to no success.

What am I doing wrong? How could I, at least, initialize the variable `Tournament` so that I don't get an undefined error while waiting for the result of the async operation?

Comment: Does the result of your console.log in the TournamentEditComponent return what you expected?

Comment: Can you post, your html ?

Comment: You could initialise the value of tournament to *something that's actually a Tournament*, not just an empty array. The fact that you had to type it as any should have been a clue that your value didn't make sense. Or use the elvis operator to safely navigate to props, or use ngIf to conditionally render once the data is available, or use the AsyncPipe to deal properly with an observable of the data you want. I'd recommend starting with https://angular.io/tutorial.

Comment: @AndrewStalker Yes, it does indeed. The problem I am having is before this data is retrieved from my server.

Comment: Players will be undefined until you have a tournament. As jonrsharpe says, manye an ngIf to conditionally render the panels would work. I'd set the initial tournament to null, and then in the accordion you could use *ngIf="tournament". See Emilien's answer.

Comment: Here's a blog post on async data I wrote a while ago: https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you can try this :

```js
export class TournamentEditComponent implements OnInit {

  tournament$: Observable<any>;

  getTournament() {
    this.tournament$ = this.restApi.getTournament(this.id);
  }
```

```html
<div *ngIf="(tournament$ | async)?.Players as players">
 <h4 class="mb-2">Players ({{ players.length }})</h4>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" activeIds="">
        <div *ngFor="let player of players">
          <ngb-panel title="{{ player.username }}">
            <ng-template ngbPanelContent>
              <p>{{ player.name }} {{ player.surname }}</p>
            </ng-template>
          </ngb-panel>
        </div>
      </ngb-accordion>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I've read a bit more about the asyncpipe and it does make a lot of sense. I've tried applying your solution, and even if I don't get any error, the ngIf directive does not get updated when the async pipe gets de data. If I understand correctly, the pipe returning data should trigger the ngIf update and display the data.

Comment: I think yes but are you sure you have an object `Players` with titlecase into `tournaments$` ? Could you post a console.log from `tournaments$` like `this.tournaments$.subscribe(console.log)` ?

Comment: Please update your post to add this console.log data :)

Comment: Into your .html file, could you make test like `<pre>{{ (tournament$ | async) | json }}</pre>` and `<pre>{{ (tournament$ | async)?.Players | json }}</pre>`

Comment: If I do it as you indicate, I get `null` in both cases. However, If I remove the $ (observable) and async clauses ( `<pre>{{ (tournament | json) }} </pre>`), I get the data correctly

Comment: Oh, that mean you miss I override the name of `tournament$` :) Generally, observables are written with a `$` to distinguish them. So, is this working now ?

Comment: I forgot to remove the subscribe operation and change it for an observable element, to be used with sync later on. This solved my issue, thanks, it seems I have lots to learn yet :).